# Which of these data sets lends itself most to classification via support vector machine?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I need to get an SVM classifier of the ground.  I don't have a lot of experience with SVM, so I was wondering, just by a cursory glance at these data sets ( http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html ), whether there is one in particular I should be using.

Comment: The 'skin segmentation' link below is  along the lines of what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a really good answer with datasets samples and a good explanation of SVM:
[Datasets to test Nonlinear SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920859/datasets-to-test-nonlinear-svm)

From the list ( http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html ) I think you should try with the [Iris Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) for **multiclass classification** or with [Skin Segmentation Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Skin+Segmentation) for **binary classification**. I think is a good start with enough and continuous data to test SVM

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I'll accept that one, if I don't get (or create) a simple "CLICK THE LINK THESE ONES" answer.  For posterity.

Comment: I'm testing one dataset for you also, I'll update this answer soon ;)

Comment: @WalrustheCat You can also take a look to an old code that I have about an AdaBoost implementation in Java to detect spam. Don't judge...was a couple years ago ;) http://code.google.com/p/spamdetection/source/browse/trunk/src/adaBoost.java

Comment: judge your code? no wai.  but your answer? maybe. isn't the iris dataset multivariate, and doesn't SVM lend itself to binary classification tasks? don't you have to do a lot of meta-work to do multivariate predictions in SVM (1 vs 2, 2 vs 3 1 vs winner of 2 vs 3? etc)  i chose the 'skin' data set from UCI and i didn't have to do any of that.  am i right? why is iris better?  muchos gracias

Comment: The Iris is a multiclass problem - it totally can be solved with SVM though. You are right, for binary classification the one you chose is good!